# How to hide/shade/disable non-clickable checkboxes in jsTree?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, jstree

I list files in directories that can be downloaded. I made the checkboxes of objects that I don't want user to be able to download non-clickable. All directories cannot be downloaded and some of the files.

But I want to **hide** the checkboxes completely. It is very confusing that the checkbox is there but cannot be used.

My sample code is on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/radek/4fTDq/13/)

Comment: Can't you just not create them in the first place? How are you getting the `data` object?

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. I was thinking about that. I will get data from ajax call. I thought that from user point of view it would be good to show them that the files exist. But if there is no solution I wouldn't include files into the tree. What about the directories?

Comment: So you want to show that the directories are there, but not display checkboxes by them? Because you could just use `[rel=directory] .jstree-checkbox { display:none }`.

Comment: Yes, for directories and the same for files. I need to separate different type of files. Weekly, daily, hourly. I thought that jsTree would be nice to use. I have almost ready solution using html `select` but jsTree will also allow me getting data of directories on demand. The directories are on different server all over the country.

Comment: The code you suggested hides all checkboxes.

Comment: According to your `data` object, both of the checkboxes are for directories (they both have `"attr":{"rel":"directory"}`). Is there a different way that you distinguish between directory checkboxes and file checkboxes?

Comment: @Radek let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2646/discussion-between-sdleihssirhc-and-radek)

Comment: Why don't you create an answer? You/we are almost there. :-) The `w-file2` shouldn't have checkbox too. The checkbox is not clickable.

Comment: Final solution here. http://jsfiddle.net/radek/4fTDq/15/ please create an answer and I'll accept it if there is no native jsTree solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, there are two quick, CSS methods for hiding the checkbox:

1. Use `display:none`
2. Use `visibility:hidden`

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmn6g/) that uses the first for directories and the second for disabled files; but it's not that big a deal. The major difference, as you saw, is that the second leaves the empty space.

Also! Important! The CSS uses the [attribute selector](http://css-tricks.com/5591-attribute-selectors/) and the [child selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/childselector), neither of which are supported in IE6.

Answer (score 3):

I think you could use load event of the tree and code like that:

```
$("#tree").bind("loaded.jstree", function (event, data) {
  $(this).find('li[rel!=file]').find('.jstree-checkbox:first').hide();
})
```

And then invoke jstree.